# When is it Safe to Dynamically Link against Libraries which Depend on Different MSVC Runtimes?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, dll, linker, runtime

I have an executable `AApp` which dynamically links a library `BLib` (`.dll`). Here is a bit of context.

- `AApp` is compiled using **VS2019 16.7**
- `BLib` is compiled using a slightly newer version, **VS2019 16.8**. I cannot change these versions.
- `AApp` uses `/MD` to link the MSVC runtime dynamically.
- I have the option to use `/MD` or `/MT` to link the runtime dynamically or
  statically for `BLib`

When is it safe to link `BLib` in `AApp` dynamically (i.e. with the `.dll` and `.lib`)? Specifically, would it be safe for me to link the library in the application dynamically when I have the library link the runtime statically **and** I ensure that a C-API interface is used between library and application to prevent using the STL or CRT types?

In terms of mixing runtime libraries, would it make a difference at all whether I build `BLib` with `/MD` or `/MT` to link the runtime dynamically or statically?

Best Regards!

Comment: I think as long as you don't deallocate memory in one binary that has been allocated by the other binary and if you don't share non trivial STL objects between the binaries you should be fine.

Comment: MSVC runtime is [backward compatible since 2015 up to current 2022](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/porting/binary-compat-2015-2017): _We've kept the Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable major version number the same for Visual Studio 2015, 2017, 2019, and 2022. That means only one instance of the Redistributable can be installed at a time. A newer version overwrites any older version that's already installed._ So, if you link all libraries to dynamic runtime `/MD` you are safe.

Comment: Hey @dewaffled, I've read that but I apparently have a wrong understanding of what that means? 
I understand that the `AApp` could link against a newer dynamic runtime library because of that binary compatibility. However, does that also mean that I can safely interface `AApp` and `BLib` even though they were compiled using different versions of VS?

Comment: Regarding the following:
*You can mix binaries built by different versions of the v140, v141, v142, and v143 toolsets. However, you must link by using a toolset at least as recent as the most recent binary in your app.* 

Does this also affect dynamic linking? I.e. I would need to link my application and my library using VS2019 16.8?

Comment: MSVC is only backwards compatible (not forwards compatible) ie the final build/link has to done with the at least the highest toolset version used to build any of the components.

Comment: @ruhigbrauner If you link to dynamic runtime only one (highest) version of redistributable will be installed and used by all components: _A newer version overwrites any older version that's already installed... For example, one app may install the Redistributable from Visual Studio 2015. Then, another app installs the Redistributable from Visual Studio 2022. The 2022 version overwrites the older version, but because they're binary-compatible, the earlier app still works fine._

Comment: @dewaffled Thanks for your comment again! So far I understand that a single (newer) redistributable can be used for both my app and library even though they both compile with different compiler versions. 

What I'm wondering here is this:
- does that also guarantee that these two libraries can interface correctly even when using STL and CRT code?
- Would compiling the library with `/MT` not produce the same result? (I understand the issue is that the statically linked code in the library might then be incompatible with the dynamically linked runtime in the app)

Comment: @RichardCritten
Would that also mean that the link between the `AApp` target and the `.lib` from my `BLib.dll` also needs to happen with the higher linker version?

Comment: @ruhigbrauner yes, all public runtime types and functions are binary compatible. But if you statically link runtime to DLL then each DLL will have separate c++ runtime heap: you cannot allocate memory in one DLL and free in another, e.g. you cannot safely consume or return STL containers across DLL boundaries.

Comment: also, regardless of heap issue, using standard library objects with mixing different runtimes linked statically is still unsafe: e.g.  if type Foo uses pimpl aproach, smth like `void *m_pimpl` `m_pimpl = create_impl()` and then `use_impl(m_pimpl)` called internally - internal implementation can be different in different runtimes so object created by `create_impl` in one DLL will not match object implementation expected by `use_impl` in another DLL.